# Displaying correct bootstrap css when <li> is an Angular component

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Okay so for Angular components the "restrict" and "replace" options are not present. I'm generally fine with this, but now I have the following code:

```
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown dropdown-menu-left"
          aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <some-component></some-component>
        <li role="separator"
            class="divider"></li>
        <li><a> Block </a></li>
      </ul>
```

where the `<some-component></some-component>` has a bunch of other `<li>` elements inside. But since the bootstrap css only works if the `<li>` is a direct child of the `<ul>`, the list-elements from `some-component` don't get styled. Any ideas what I could do as a workaround?

Comment: You can move `some-component` into the `li` and give some custom style to it via class and use it everywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work since some-component has multiple <li>'s and then e.g. the padding between those li's is wrong

Comment: I typically copy bootstrap's css for the relevant items and update the selectors as needed.  Kinda sucks, but if you're using bootstrap-sass it isn't as bad.